# How to proxy request in Jhipster Gateway?

Tags: java, spring, jhipster, netflix-zuul

I have created couple micro-services and a **jhipster-gateway** using https://start.jhipster.tech/#/

In gateway all API from microservices are available but I need to pass microservice name in request prefix. For example

```
http://localhost:8080/user-service/api/user
http://localhost:8080/pet-service/api/pets
```

In place of this, I want to configure it such that I do not need to pass service name in path url as below

```
http://localhost:8080/api/user
http://localhost:8080/api/pets
```

I have tried to fix it with `zuul` configuration as below

```
zuul: 
    sensitive-headers: Cookie,Set-Cookie
    host:
        max-total-connections: 1000
        max-per-route-connections: 100
    semaphore:
        max-semaphores: 500
    routes:
        pets:
            path: /api/pets/**
            serviceId: pet-service
            stripPrefix: true
        users:
            path: /api/user/**
            serviceId: user-service
            stripPrefix: true
```

I had followed this demo from founding members. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FuG5t_UW7pw

PS: I am new to Jhipster and evaluating it for my next project. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not as easy as just configuring routes in yaml, you will need to modify code to support swagger url rewriting, access control filter, route locator, etc.. Not very complex code but you'll need to configure it somehow. BTW, your title is wrong, it's about proxying requests not redirecting them.

Comment: the video is 2h41m long, but thank you very much! (I *love* english with french (any type of) accent xD) seen/found this (searching for 'jhispter+zuul') : https://www.jhipster.tech/traefik/ ? (but sorry, not fit for an answer/ your 50 rep. yet.))

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should set the prefix in zuul and setup the path mappings. Following the example below:

```
zuul.prefix=/api //define a path for the gateway
zuul.ignored-services=* //ignore services that mustn't exposed
zuul.routes.userService.path=/users/** //map of service
zuul.routes.userService.serviceId=user-service
zuul.routes.userService.path=/pets/**
zuul.routes.petService.serviceId=pet-service
```

Sory for post my answer in properties and not in yaml.